# What makes Woody say "Chutes and Ladders"?

Tags: toy-story-4

In *Toy Story 4* (2019), after Forky jumps into a trash bin, Woody says:

> Woody: Oh, **Chutes and Ladders**!

What makes Woody say "Chutes and Ladders"?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

"Chutes and Ladders" is the American name for the popular board game [Snakes and Ladders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snakes_and_Ladders). In context, Woody is clearly using it as a toy-themed "minced oath" (a family-friendly version of a swear word). Note that "Chute" is one vowel sound away from "Shit".

Comment: As another layer, some media will already use "shoot" as a [minced oath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) in this context - they're just adapting it to a toy / game theme

Comment: Don't forget also that Woody is an incredibly "wholesome" character from the '50s, who might even view a minced oath like "shoot" as ungentlemanly.  Beyond the toy-related pun, using an "even-more-minced oath" to replace a "minced oath" fits with his character.

Comment: Worth noting that "Chutes and Ladders" is the name that Americans typically know the game by.  In the commonwealth it's known as "Snakes and Ladders", but Americans would probably look at you sideways if you asked them what that was.  The snakes were replaced with playground slides because, evidently, American kids found snakes scary in 1943.

Comment: @J..., Well yes, basically, on American playgrounds, kids climb up a ladder, and then they slide down a chute. They don't slide down a snake. If you ask an American child who's visiting a Commonwealth country to slide down a snake, they probably _will_ look at you "sideways." Doesn't matter how friendly or accommodating the snake actually is.

Comment: But... Americans slide down slides, not chutes.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The point was that the game did not have a playground theme *until* the US version introduced it as such.  Obviously playground slides make sense in the context of the American game.  The game as known outside the US, however, has nothing to do with playgrounds.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Are slides (or chutes) not a common feature of playgrounds basically everywhere?  (Quick Google street view search for "Playgrounds" in London confirms, though not sure if this was true in the 1940's...)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, I took this to be the main joke here. He's so absurdly wholesome he can't even bear to say a harmless word like "shoot".

Comment: @J... In fact the game ([snakes, ladders, and all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyan_chauper)) pre-dates playground slides (first installed in the 1900s) by around 1800 years...  I think we can understand why the Indians decided to use a venomous animal to represent being set back instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if the goal was to make it "even more minced" or just to be a pun on "shoot" which is already a well-known exclamation in American vernacular (and likely moreso in the time frame from which Woody is set.)

Comment: @J...: Can't speak for all Americans, but I think of both names equivalently; I'd understand either name equally readily. Hasbro may only make Chutes and Ladders, but other brands sell discount versions under the Snakes and Ladders name, and you get an eclectic mix when daycares and schools take whatever people will donate.

Comment: Since Woody is a toy, it makes sense that he would reference a game in his variation of the minced oath.